# WSO2 identity server SMS OTP Authentication folder not deploying when changed to different environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, identity-management

I'm using identity server v5.10.0, I'm changing only the UI of smsotp.jsp and mobile.jsp and whenever I run the jenkins job and switch it to a different environment, the sms OTP authentication gets deployed with the default war file and existing folder with the UI changes is not deployed. if I zip and paste in a different env the entire folder UI changes are present but whenever I take it through jenkins the SMS OTP folder gets deployed from the default war file. Can anyone from WSO2 team help here and let me know how to proceed further

Any help here is much Appreciated.

Comment: During your Jenkins job, do you explode the smsotpauthenticationendpoint.war and change the smsotp.jsp and mobile.jsp files in the exploded smsotpauthenticationendpoint folder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue on how you are deploying the modified files. As @anuradha-karunarathna suggested in comments, you can try exploding the smsotpauthenticationendpoint.war, change the smsotp.jsp and mobile.jsp files in the exploded smsotpauthenticationendpoint directory and then deploy it within your pipeline.